# Stored procedure inserting values into a table using Table-Valued Parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given the following simple structure:

```
TABLE: Product (ProductId, ProductName)

TABLE: Category (CategoryId, CategoryName)

LINK TABLE: ProductId,CategoryId
```

I have a table type which I want to pass to a stored procedure to insert the values into another table if they don't exist.

```
CREATE TYPE StringList_TBLType AS TABLE (s NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
```

I want to do the following in a stored procedure where I pass in a ProductName, and the StringList_TBLType of Category Names

1. select all the strings from my StringList_TBLType
2. Insert the string into the Category TABLE if it does not exist
3. Get the ID of the inserted or already existing Category
4. Insert the ProductId, and CategoryId into the LINK TABLE.

I could probably struggle along and get something working, but I have little experience with MS SQL, and stored procedures in general, and am scared that I would end up writing a very inefficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `MERGE` statement to capture the category IDs.

```
DECLARE @changes TABLE  (ChangeID VARCHAR(10), Id INTEGER);
DECLARE @JustSomeRandomVariable INT;

MERGE Category AS TARGET
USING @data AS SOURCE
    ON TARGET.Category = SOURCE.s
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([Category])
    VALUES (SOURCE.s)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET @JustSomeRandomVariable = 1
OUTPUT $action, inserted.Id INTO @changes;
```

The random variable in the merge statement makes sure that updates get logged into the @changes table variable.

Now you can use the @changes to update your link table.

```
INSERT INTO Link SELECT ProductID, ChangeID FROM @changes
```

Just retrieve the required ProductID with a simple select query.

**EDIT:**

This could potentially result in double records in the Link table. You might need to tweak it a bit, perhaps use the MERGE statement for inserting into the Link table aswell.

@data is the StringList_TBLType paramter of your procedure.

Comment: Interesting... Never heard of merge before, but after some reading, it looks like the @changes table would only have the id's of new categories? I need the ids of existing categories also, as both need to go into the link table

Comment: I did a test for myself (SQL Server 2008 R2) and by adding the assigned too `@JustSomeRandomVariable` for updates it captures the updates in @changes aswell.

Comment: Ah, sounds like I should give it a go and see what happens!

Comment: JodyT, It took me a while to get this working as my stored procedure is 141 lines long and I'm new to this. It was frustrating, but I have learnt a lot and appreciate your help with such an elegant solution! Many many thanks.

Comment: Hi JodyT, I am having duplicate records in the link table, but I'm struggling to understand why this happens. Why would the MERGE produce the categoryId twice in certain cases?

Comment: If you call the stored procedure with the same product and 1 or more of the same categories twice, then it will also insert them into the `Link` table twice. Unless you check yourself if the relation already exists in the `Link` table.

Comment: That's what I thought... I must be passing a duplicate category. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would suggest (not tested)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddProductToCategories 
@productname nvarchar(255),
@categories StringList_TBLType READONLY
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @productId bigint --change to datatype of Product.ProductId
SET @productId = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductId FROM Product WHERE ProductName = @productname) --What to do if your product names are not unique?

IF @productId is not NULL
BEGIN

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR (
    SELECT cat.CategoryName, cat.CategoryId, c.s
    FROM @categories c
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN Category cat on c.s = cat.CategoryName
)

DECLARE @id as bigint --change to datatype of Category.CategoryId
DECLARE @name as nvarchar(255) --change to datatype of Category.CategoryName
DECLARE @categoryNameToAdd as nvarchar(255)

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name, @id, @categoryNameToAdd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @id is NULL
    BEGIN
        --category does not exist yet in table Category
        INSERT INTO Category (CategoryName) VALUES (@categoryNameToAdd)
        SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

    INSERT INTO ProductsCategories --your link table
    (ProductId, CategoryId)
    VALUES
    (@productId, @id) 


    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @name, @id, @categoryNameToAdd
END --cursor


CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
END --IF @productId
END --sproc
```

Comment: I would avoid using cursors unless there is no other way. And if you do really need cursors then you need to think twice if you want to solve it in T-SQL.

Comment: In general they require more code (harder to maintain) and have a worse performance.